# Filter fetch data react

Tags: reactjs, filter, fetch, fetch-api

Why filter by search work but by drop-down list not?
I don't know why this is so, maybe someone sees some error.

I would like to filter tags using checkboxes. It was hard for me to find a tutorial on the internet, I was able to find filtering by searching. It turned out that everything was set up successfully, then I wanted to set filtering by list, but here I have a problem. I don't know why the list search doesn't work - even though it seems to work on the console.

demo here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-wu-rt4wd?file=/src/styles.css

```
  const [filterParam, setFilterParam] = useState(['All'])
  const [q, setQ] = useState('')
  const [searchParam] = useState(['tags'])
```

```
   function search(data) {
    return data.filter((item) => {
      if (item.tags == filterParam) {
        return searchParam.some((newItem) => {
          return (
            item[newItem].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1
          )
        })
      } else if (filterParam == 'All') {
        return searchParam.some((newItem) => {
          return (
            item[newItem].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1
          )
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

```
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor='search-form'>
          <input
            type='search'
            name='search-form'
            id='search-form'
            className='search-input'
            placeholder='Search for...'
            value={q}
            onChange={(e) => setQ(e.target.value)}
          />
          <span className='sr-only'>Search countries here</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className='select'>
        <select
          onChange={(e) => {
            setFilterParam(e.target.value)
            // console.log(setFilterParam(e.target.value.toString()))
            console.log(e.target.value.toString())
          }}
          aria-label='Filter Countries By Region'
        >
          <option value='All'>All</option>
          <option value='accessibility'>accessibility</option>
          <option value='javascript'>javascript</option>
          <option value='css'>css</option>
          <option value='advanced'>advanced</option>
          <option value='svg'>svg</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <section className={styles.main}>
        {search(data).map((item) => (
          <div className={styles.card}>
            <div>
              <div className={styles.card__first}>
                <div className={styles.card__name}>
                  <FaTwitter className={styles.card__icon} />

                  <span className={styles.card__author}>{item.authorId}</span>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.card__price}>
                  <p>{item.price}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className={styles.card__title}>
                <h1>{item.title}</h1>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p className={styles.card__desc}>{item.description}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.card__tags}>
              {item.tags.map((t) => {
                return (
                  <div className={styles.card__tag}>
                    <p>{t}</p>
                  </div>
                )
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </section>

    </>
  )
}

export default Page
```

Comment: Try with replacing default to useState('All')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change a lot of things, you can try this example

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import styles from "./App.module.css";
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const [filterParam, setFilterParam] = useState("All");
  const [q, setQ] = useState("");
  const [searchParam, setSearchParam] = useState([]);

  const getData = () => {
    fetch("data.json", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (myJson) {
        console.log(myJson);
        setData(myJson);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  function search(data) {
    return data.filter(
      (item) =>
        (filterParam === "All" || item.tags.includes(filterParam)) &&
        (searchParam.length === 0 ||
          (searchParam.every((tag) => item.tags.includes(tag)) &&
            JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1))
    );
  }

  const inputChangedHandler = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const index = searchParam.indexOf(value);
    if (index > -1) {
      const updatedParam = [...searchParam];
      updatedParam.splice(index, 1);
      setSearchParam(updatedParam);
    } else {
      setSearchParam([...searchParam, event.target.value]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="search-form">
          <input
            type="search"
            name="search-form"
            id="search-form"
            className="search-input"
            placeholder="Search for..."
            value={q}
            onChange={(e) => setQ(e.target.value)}
          />
          <span className="sr-only">Search countries here</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="select">
        <select
          onChange={(e) => {
            setFilterParam(e.target.value);
            // console.log(setFilterParam(e.target.value.toString()))
            console.log(e.target.value.toString());
          }}
          aria-label="Filter Countries By Region"
        >
          <option value="All">All</option>
          <option value="accessibility">accessibility</option>
          <option value="javascript">javascript</option>
          <option value="css">css</option>
          <option value="advanced">advanced</option>
          <option value="svg">svg</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id="topping"
          name="advanced"
          value="advanced"
          onChange={inputChangedHandler}
        />
        advanced
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id="topping"
          name="javascript"
          value="javascript"
          onChange={inputChangedHandler}
        />
        javascript
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id="topping"
          name="fundamentals"
          value="fundamentals"
          onChange={inputChangedHandler}
        />
        fundamentals
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id="topping"
          name="css"
          value="css"
          onChange={inputChangedHandler}
        />
        css
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id="topping"
          name="svg"
          value="svg"
          onChange={inputChangedHandler}
        />
        svg
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id="topping"
          name="accessibility"
          value="accessibility"
          onChange={inputChangedHandler}
        />
        accessibility
      </div>
      <section className={styles.main}>
        {search(data).map((item) => (
          <div className={styles.card}>
            <div>
              <div className={styles.card__first}>
                <div className={styles.card__name}>
                  <p className={styles.card__icon}>ICON</p>

                  <span className={styles.card__author}>{item.authorId}</span>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.card__price}>
                  <p>{item.price}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className={styles.card__title}>
                <h1>{item.title}</h1>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p className={styles.card__desc}>{item.description}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.card__tags}>
              {item.tags.map((t) => {
                return (
                  <div className={styles.card__tag}>
                    <p>{t}</p>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </section>

      {/* <Margins>
      <Header data={data} />
      <Main data={data} />
    </Margins> */}
    </>
  );
}
```

[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-sound-b3vm3?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you very very much !!

Comment: How can i add another filter i mean if i would like to filter price something like "<$10", "$10-$20", ">$20"